# Basic struts 2 application for understanding

Tags: java, struts2

I started reading about **struts2** yesterday and came across the below slide. Site [link](http://www.jeetrainers.com/course/struts2_chapter1_wep_applications-2-1-1)
[image]

It gave a good picture of what can be done with struts2, I want if somebody can demonstrate the above image with an example working code for a simple CRUD webapp (with simple empid and empname in db) . This can turn out to be a nice tutorial for others too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home)

It can create a project skeleton using a variety of web frameworks (including Struts 2) for you to experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse.html) gives a basic CRUD overview